# AngularJS Controller Method parameter not getting data changes?

Tags: angularjs, methods, parameters, controller, arguments

My issue is related to AngularJS. I am showing JSON data in table rows. My issue is that I am getting unedited data instead of edited data in controller's methods(`$scope.save(arg)` & `$scope.export(arg)`) as argument. Whereas I wish to get edited data in controller's methods(`$scope.save(arg)` & `$scope.export(arg)`) so that I can:

1. export the data changes to file.
2. `$scope.export(arg)` method is saving unedited data to file on windows laptop but does not allow to save data in file in Cordova Android app.
3. wish to replace the unedited object with edited object in `$scope.padas[]`, array of objects, and save the array as JSON file (guess work is available below).

What I have tried so far is available below as well as at jsfiddle. Appreciate valuable guidance to fix the issue.

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hd6rxe8u/1/)**

**HTML**

```
<body layout="row" ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl" ng-cloak>
  <main layout="column" flex aria-hidden="false">
    <md-content ng-ref="container" md-scroll-y flex>
      <md-subheader>
        <div layout=row layout-align="space-around center">
          <md-icon class="material-icons" ng-init="editMode=false" ng-click="editMode=!editMode">
            edit
          </md-icon>
          <!-- problem -->
          <md-icon class="material-icons" ng-click="save(oPada)">save</md-icon>
          <md-icon class="material-icons" ng-click="export(oPada)">download</md-icon>
          <!-- problem -->
          <md-icon class="material-icons">swipe</md-icon>
        </div>
      </md-subheader>

      <div contenteditable="{{editMode}}">
        <div class="padaBody">
          <table class="padaLyrics">
            <tr ng-repeat="line in oPada.lyrics track by $index">
              <td>{{line}}</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>

    </md-content>
  </main>
</body>
```

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('mainApp', ['ngMaterial']);
angular.module('mainApp')
  .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $sce, $http, $window) {

    $scope.padas = [{
        "padaID": 730,
        "title": "What is Lorem Ipsum",
        "lyrics": [
          "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text",
          "of the printing and typesetting",
          "industry. Lorem Ipsum has been",
          "the industry's standard dummy",
        ]
      },
      {
        "padaID": 735,
        "title": "Why do we use it",
        "lyrics": [
          "It is a long established fact that",
          "a reader will be distracted by the",
          "readable content of a page",
          "when looking at its layout."
        ]
      }
    ];
    $scope.oPada = $scope.padas[0];

    // Save array as JSON file with data changes
    $scope.save = function(objectToSave) {
      if (!objectToSave) {
        return;
      }
      // save edited data to json
      $http.put('data/pada.json', objectToSave).then(
        function(response) {
          $scope.editMode = false;
          // find edited pada by id in padas array
          const idx = $scope.padas.findIndex(o => o.padaID === response.data.padaID);
          // replace dound pada in array with edited pada(response.data)
          $scope.padas.splice(idx, 1, response.data);
        },
        function(response) {}
      );
    };

    // Export data changes to save in file.
    $scope.export = function(objectToExport) {
      objectToExport = objectToExport || {
        string: "empty",
        number: 2
      };
      const pada = objectToExport.title ?
        objectToExport.title.replace(/ /g, '_') :
        objectToExport.padaID ?
        'PadaID_' + objectToExport.padaID.toString().padStart(3, '0') :
        'PadaID_000';
      const filename = pada + '.json';
      var blob = new Blob([angular.toJson(objectToExport, true)], {
        type: 'text/text'
      });
      if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, filename);
      } else {
        var e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents'),
          a = document.createElement('a');
        a.download = filename;
        a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.dataset.downloadurl = ['text/json', a.download, a.href].join(':');
        e.initEvent('click', true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
        a.dispatchEvent(e);
      }
    };
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using proper input elements such as `textarea` instead of `contenteditable`, and using `ng-model`.

For example, instead of this

```
  <div contenteditable="{{editMode}}">
    <div class="padaBody">
      <table class="padaLyrics">
        <tr ng-repeat="line in oPada.lyrics track by $index">
          <td>{{line}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

try this, with ng-model allowing the underlying data to be updated correctly.

```
<textarea aria-label="label" ng-model="oPada.lyrics[0]"></textarea>
```

Though, you'll need a new solution for your multi-line input as this is for inputting/editing one single block of text, not an array like you have. This is why just for the sake of demonstration, I've only bound the first lyric to the textarea (`oPada.lyrics[0]`)

Comment: Thanks to reply. 1) textarea is not suitable as I have to display text line by line and also I need to allow user editing only if there is any error in text. I am able to extract changes from table rows.  2) can $http.put() method save changes in Cordova Android App without server is the BIG question now?

Comment: The stuff about `$http.put()` is a whole other question, but basically `contenteditable` does not work with `ng-model` or simply handlebars `{{}}`, so you'll need a custom solution. I.e. make your own `contenteditable`. If you google "angularjs contenteditable", there are some examples but you'll need to expand it to work with multiple lines